# Zinnia (handwriting recognition) and PHP integration

Tags: php, ocr, handwriting

Can anyone please provide some instructions or steps on how to integrate [zinnia](http://zinnia.sourceforge.net) (handrecognition system) with regular php? A sample of how it works could be found [here](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/ajax/hwr/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It says `Thread-safe C/C++/Perl/Ruby/Python libraries`, so I guess you can't use it with PHP.

Place a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=232651&atid=1087001) for PHP wrappers with the [project space at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zinnia/).

Comment: Or at least, not directly. Some kind of command line interface would be needed for PHP to connect to the libraries. Or, of course, a custom PHP extension.

Comment: The wrappers have been built with SWIG. SWIG can do PHP too, so the OP could place a feature request with the project space at sourceforge.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your answer. But how difficult is it to create a PHP wrapper for Zinnia? Seems like zinnia support is not very active, so I suppose I'll have to do everything on my own...

Comment: Depends on your skill with C++ I guess. I have no clue. You'd have to look into the Zinnia sources and http://www.swig.org