# Handwritten text recognition php

Tags: php

I am thinking of creating a certain web system. It involves a lot of different (random) people uploading scanned documents of stuff they wrote.

Is there any PHP open source way converting these handwritten texts to machine text?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947706/zinnia-handwriting-recognition-and-php-integration) but would like to know if it is capable of recognizing a lot of random & different people's writing?

Do anyone have experience to share of this field?

Comment: FYI this is called [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See related question on SO: [handwriting recognition with simple training](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6133410/377657)

Image-based handwriting recognition is also known as [Off-line handwriting recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition#Off-line_recognition).

If the handwritten characters are always [capital-letter, post-office style](http://www.writingwizard.longcountdown.com/files/worksheet20064224058846.html), it can be handled by [Intelligent Character Recognition (ICR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_character_recognition), which is image-based.

The difference between off-line (image-based) and on-line (real-time) recognition is that the latter requires you to record the timestamp (position and velocity) of each stroke as it is being written.

An image-based recognition engine can handle on-line data by converting the timestamped strokes into an image. To the contrary, an on-line recognition engine *cannot* handle image-based inputs. As such, on-line recognition is technically easier and open-source projects are available.

Several Wikipedia articles contain lists of OCR/ICR software providers:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_character_recognition_software
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_character_recognition

An example of on-line handwriting recognition engine (open-source):

- http://tegaki.org/

Answer (score 2):

i have done ocr from php using tesseract-ocr

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

the results weren't that great, and i doubt it supports handwriting
but i would be interested to see what others have done

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as hand-writing differs too much that a computer program can find the pattern to recognize the text in there. You can try with OCR, ideally with a library that interfaces well with PHP e.g. via shell for a starter. See [Ocrad - The GNU OCR](http://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/ocrad.html).