# Integrate hand written notes in web application and store in database

Tags: javascript, php

There is a requirement where client wants to hand written notes feature integrated in web application and it should be stored in database.

For example, there will be an icon on the web app. By clicking on it, it will open popup/textarea where user can write/take notes using stylus and that note/text will be stored in database say in binary type.

I searched for plugins which I can include in the web application, but I could not find useful information.

Do you guys know about any plugin? Any help in this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976148/handwritten-text-recognition-php

Take a look at that.

Comment: what do you mean by `hand written notes`? are they images? or you want user to write in your application.

Comment: @urfusion no there are not images. let's say user clicks some icon in the web app, popup will open, user will write some text using stylus and that text will be stored in database say in binary type..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple projects on Github which support server side OCR in PHP. Try for example: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Here it is.

https://dev.myscript.com/

MyScript, you can embed in your web application. I am still implementing a solution.

I will share it once it is done.